# Use Android Ui automator 2.0,How to get ActivityName?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am using Uiautomator 2.0, which supports `UiDevice.getCurrentActivity()` to get `currentActivity` Name. However the results is not what I expect, instead it gets the App's Name.

What do I use to get the name of the current activity?

Comment: Seems like `getCurrentActivityName()` method is deprecated. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html says "The results returned should be considered unreliable"

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `getCurrentActivityName()` method is deprecated. developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/… says "The results returned should be considered unreliable."

Though one of the ways to get the name list of activities of your application is using command prompt :

```
adb shell dumpsys activity | grep <package>
```

which could provide you with the list of activities active on your package.

```
* Recent #0: TaskRecord...
```

statement further includes the activities you have triggered using INTENT in your application and

```
mFocusedActivity:...
```

statement would specify the currently focussed activity of your application.